# Use External Notifier in AWS with SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I am using AWS with Codedeploy and Codepipeline, with Git to push our PHP codes and I want to use Discord or any free service to Notify our Pipeline status

Answer (score 0):

EventBridge service provide codepipeline notification. Trigger it to SNS for email notification or lambda function for custom action

Available EventBridge event for codepipeline:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/detect-state-changes-cloudwatch-events.html

Telegram notification python example (you can try other application API)
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/simple-telegram-bot-with-python-and-aws-lambda-5eab1066b466